# How come Mockito mocks worked in my tests without annotation

Tags: java, junit, mocking, mockito

I run my tests without `@RunWith` and `initMocks()`. Shouldn't it be not working?

```
public class MultiFilesIteratorInMemoryTest {
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {

    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {

    }

    @Test
    public void getNextLine() throws Exception {

    }

    @Test
    public void timeFrameIsSplitIntoTwoFilesReturnAllRelevantRecords() throws Exception {

        IRandomAccess randomAccessFile1 = mock(RandomAccessFileWrapper.class);
        IRandomAccess randomAccessFile2 = mock(RandomAccessFileWrapper.class);
        IFileUtils fileUtils = mock(FileUtils.class);

        when(randomAccessFile1.readLine()).thenReturn("first file content").thenReturn(null);
        when(randomAccessFile2.readLine()).thenReturn("second file content").thenReturn(null);
        when(fileUtils.getCountOfSimilarNamedFilesFromDir(anyString())).thenReturn(2);

        IMultiFilesMerger multiFilesMerger = new MultiFilesIteratorInMemory(fileUtils, ImmutableList.of(randomAccessFile1, randomAccessFile2));


        String nextLine = multiFilesMerger.getNextLine();
        assertThat(nextLine, equalTo("first file content"));
        nextLine = multiFilesMerger.getNextLine();
        assertThat(nextLine, equalTo("second file content"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it will work just fine because you are explicitly creating your mocks and they are not injected.

[`MockitoJUnitRunner`](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/1.9.5/org/mockito/runners/MockitoJUnitRunner.html) is only used to inject mocks that are annotated with `@Mock`:

> Initializes mocks annotated with Mock, so that explicit usage of `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(Object)` is not necessary.

The same goes for [`initMocks`](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/1.9.5/org/mockito/MockitoAnnotations.html#initMocks%28java.lang.Object%29):

> `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);` initializes fields annotated with Mockito annotations.

In your code, you aren't using Mockito annotated fields with `@Mock` or `@InjectMocks`. Instead, you are explicitly creating the mocks with the [`mock`](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/1.9.5/org/mockito/Mockito.html#mock%28java.lang.Class%29) static factory.